# high sierra bash shell script how to change directory

Tags: bash, macos-high-sierra

I work with high sierra and I have the following shell script

```
TOMCAT_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.12/
cd ./webapp/inventory/WEB-INF
rm -r -v classes
mkdir classes
cp -R ../../../classes ./classes
cd ..
jar -cvf inventory.war WEB-INF
cp inventory.war $TOMCAT_PATH/webapps
cd ../..
```

How can I execute the command

```
cd ./webapp/inventory/WEB-INF
```

After this cd the directory doesn't change

The current directory

```
/Users/carlotavina/Documents/carlota/irvine/javaenterprisedevelopment/curso6-webservices/week2/assignment/HW-2_Setup
```

In this directory I have subdirectory `webapp/inventory`. I want to move to this directory

Comment: Does `webapp/inventory` have a `WEB-INF` directory? What's the actual error you get when you try to run the script?

Comment: I get No such file or directoryp/inventory/WEB-INF.  webapp/inventory has WEB-INF

Comment: It looks like your script has DOS line endings, so you are really trying to switch to the directory `webapp/inventory/WEB-INF\r`, not `webapp/inventory/WEB-INF`. Fix your script with `dos2unix`, or see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info (under Before asking about problematic code
) for more details.

Comment: This script really should have either `set -e` at  the beginning (which'll make the script exit if any command fails) or explicit error checking on most steps, especially the `cd` commands. Otherwise, if one command fails, the rest of the script will continue to run in unexpected places/ways.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Very true. Shellcheck complains that you should append `|| exit` or `|| return` after each `cd` statement because of exactly that.